# How to do Multiple Condition in SQL query using PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I have databse in MySQL with 21 fields which are listed below

```
Field Name  Data Type       NULL
status      text        No           
roll_no     text        No           
branch_id       int(5)      No           
student_name    text        No           
father_name     text        No           
phone1      text        No           
phone2      text        No           
email       text        No           
dob         date        No           
city        text        No           
course_id       varchar(5)  No           
class_id        int(2)      No           
program     text        No           
duration        text        No           
comment     text        No           
admission_year  int(4)      No           
admission_date  text        No           
entryby     text        No           
address     text        No           
admission_no    int(4)      No
fees        int(6)      No
```

Now I am stuck with search process, I bit confused, how can I perform search for different types of conditions/criteria

Few Examples of combinations of conditions

1. Only those records of city=3
2. Only those branch_id=2
3. Only those admission_year='2013'
4. Only those course_id='15'
5. Only those branch_id='2' AND  course_id='15'
6. Only those branch_id='2' AND  course_id='15' AND city LIKE 'XYZ'
7. Only those admission_year='2012' AND  course_id='10' AND duration BETWEEN(2 AND 3)
8. Only those branch_id=2 AND  course_id='15' AND student_name LIKE 'XYZ'
9. Only those course_id=7 AND  class_id=2 AND father_name LIKE 'XYZ'

My search.php form page is designed, I uploaded the [image of form design here](http://cbsecsnip.in/searchForm.JPG) but I am confused how can I implement this search options for different situations.

Please give me some guidance and show me the correct way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's just plain SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city="3" AND branch_id=2 AND admission_year=2013 ...
```

Note that all fields of type `int` must not have quotes ( " " ) around them.

Comment: if some condition is not have any value than your query will give error.

Comment: @hexbolt Thanx for help. I am already aware of SQL my confusion is how I can pass values to mysql select query in PHP, well this also I know I can use php variable which I have to pass in sql query, now issue is WHAT IF I just want to view all records of city="3".
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city="3"

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi: this was meant as a guide, not a ready made solution. Plus, most are selects which will always have a value, and a lot more that just checking for empty should be done on textfields.

Comment: I simply like to know do I need multiple php if conditions for all my different sql queries or there is any simple way to do this. Suppose I have 50 different types of conditions then what I should do? I am not asking do complete my homework, I just want to guidance what is the way to complete my home work

Comment: you basically need to check one by one the fields you expect for : existence (if they have been filled in), which is done similar to @Suresh Kamrushi's answer, and sanitize them according to the expected data type ( eg `int` columns with `intval()` ). You then concatenate arguments to form an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You can do like below:

```
$search = "";
if(isset($records_of_city) && $records_of_city != "")
  $search .= "records_of_city = 3 AND";
if(isset($branch_id) && $branch_id != "")
  $search .= "branch_id = 3 AND";

if(isset($admission_year) && $admission_year != "")
  $search .= "admission_year = 3 AND";
// Continue till all search criteria are appended to $search
// And at the end

$query = "SELECT * from tableName where $serach active_status = 'active'"
```

In query only those criteria will get appended who having some values otherwise will be ignored. One more thing is we are adding AND operator after each IF condition so you need to add one condition at the end of query (You can set condition user status, delete status etc ) so that query will not gives any error.

Comment: thank you for your guidance. So what I understand from your code I have to write multiple if condition for all my possible combinations.

Comment: can you please tell me what does active_status='active' represent in the query you written in your reply.

Comment: you need a compulsory condition to be attached at the end. so just added on dummy condition, just ammend as per your requirement